# Alterar fonte com Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Preciso alterar a fonte de um sistema, não tenho acesso ao HTML, apenas via TagManager do Google, portanto preciso alterar o DOM com JS.

Não obtive sucesso, qual a melhor maneira para isso?

```js
  var a = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
  var body1 = document.getElementByTagName("body");
  newFont = document.createElement("link");
  newFont.href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa";
  body1.appendChild(a);
  a.appendChild(newFont);
```

```css
.body{
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
 }
```

Comment: Não faltou adicionar `newFont` em `a`?

Comment: Sim, só não coloquei no exemplo, mas de qualquer maneira não funcionou.

Comment: Então edite a pergunta e faça um exemplo que reproduza exatamente o que você fez. Fora isso, existe um elemento que possui a **classe** `body`?

Comment: Sim, adicionei o código completo no exemplo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta você adicionar o valor de `rel` do seu elemento `<link>` e corrigir o CSS, pois está utilizando `.body` ao invés de `body`.

```js
const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
const link = document.createElement('link');

link.rel = 'stylesheet';
link.href = 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa&display=swap';

head.appendChild(link);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque aliquam condimentum mi. Vestibulum dolor nulla, maximus et nulla vitae, tincidunt pharetra velit. Phasellus et congue lectus. Nam pretium, nisi varius interdum lobortis, felis lorem venenatis velit, eu tristique mauris ex et tortor. Aenean euismod tincidunt ligula id venenatis. Vestibulum faucibus est sed massa tempor, a luctus libero mattis. Vestibulum dapibus nulla justo, et hendrerit leo maximus non. Mauris commodo nisl eu sapien efficitur blandit. Vivamus egestas velit velit, porta maximus erat tincidunt quis. Sed id pharetra tellus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris lobortis semper congue.</p>
```